# How to securely use docker container registry credentials in production devices

Tags: docker, containers, azure-container-registry

I have a raspberry pi device which is using docker containers from private Azure container registry. The issue is where do I save the registry credentials on my device as that is a security risk. Any best practices on how to use the credentials securely. Or is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Two common solutions are to use an access token that gives limited access (e.g. pull access to specific repositories) and a credential helper that moves the credential storage elsewhere. Realize that the credential helper should return a clear text credential, but it may have a shorter lifetime or depend on the user login session. For azure, they have [a credential helper for their cloud platform](https://github.com/Azure/acr-docker-credential-helper) that should help.